# Why Google Analytics include my click after I installed it by Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have installed Google Analytics by Google Tag Manager, but every time I enter my website and click something, Google Analytics includes my click. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of methods that you can use to prevent google analytics tracking your own activity on your site:

Apply an exclude filter to exclude activity from your IP address
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034840?hl=en

Install Google's GA Opt-out browser addon
https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout

Use a 3rd party addon/extension such as ghostery, configured to block google analytics tracking
https://www.ghostery.com/